# Putting three divs on a single line

Tags: html, asp.net

I have three divs that I am trying to put on a single line. I want one to always snap left, and I want one to always snap right. The third one, which the display will be toggled using javascript, has to always be center. I've tried float. I've tried display:inline-block. Nothing works. Below is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="header" class="AppBackColor" style="color:#FFFFFF; padding:2px; width:100%; height:34px;">
<div style="height:100%;display:inline-block;float:left;">
    <img src="Images/Logo/uss_logo_white.gif" height="30px" width="31px" alt="USS" />
    <label>Change Control</label>
</div>                    
<div id="TimeoutWarning" style="height:100%; width:450px;display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;">Your session will expire in <label id="lblSessionCountDown">5:00</label>. Click <a style="color: Red;" href="#" onclick="ResetSession();void(0);">OK</a> to continue your session.</div>
<div style="height:100%;display:inline-block;float:right;">
    <label>User:</label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnLogout" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logout-icon.png" onclick="btnLogout_Click" Height="30px" Width="30px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: use `table` . . .  have 1 tr and 3 td . . possible [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430895/three-div-in-a-single-row?rq=1)

Comment: Putting divs on one line usually requires float. You could use float: left;, and float: right; but I'm not sure what you would need to do for the center one.

Comment: I've tried a table, but when the display of the div in the middle td gets set to none, the far right td slides all the way over instead of staying on right side.

I've also tried floats, but they don't stay on the same line, the UI looks like a set of stairs gradually stepping down from left to right.

Comment: One way to do this is to put the 3 divs all as float, and make sure they all take up full space, meaning, put width:33.33% each. Then inside those divs, you can align some spans.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:c#] tag since, as written, the question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430895/three-div-in-a-single-row?rq=1

Comment: I can't do 33% on each, because the far right div can grow based on the value in the label set in the c# code behind.

Comment: As far as I know not all browsers know floating or at least if they do they render somehow different. This is why floating is still annoying. You may give every div a width and a left-position rather then any float-tags.

Comment: @user3845384 Based on your last comment I would still say RealitDysfunction's approach is the right way to do it; but you might try floating all three Divs left and then using margins/padding/aligns in the right most div.

Comment: I've researched and tried everything suggested. It still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to do it. The order of the `div`s in the HTML being `left, right, center` is important, since otherwise the `right` [will place itself](http://jsfiddle.net/rq79a/1/) below the `left` and `center` elements. [See it live at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6RBQ/4/) (with JS to hide/show the center). Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="left">left text</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="center">center</div>
```

And CSS:

```css
.left, .center, .right {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Yes it puts them in the right places horizontally, but vertically they are not aligned.

Comment: @user3845384 have you tried it with the divs in the order `left, right, center` as I have it, instead of `left, center, right`? I'm not sure exactly why, but doing it the latter way does cause vertical misalignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning like this:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FAA;
}

.second {
  width: auto;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 100px; // 1st div width
  margin-right: 200px; // 3rd div width
  background-color: #AFA;
}

.third {
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #AAF;
}
```

And then use a `<div class="container">` which has inside the 3 divs with classes `first`, `second` and `third`.

If you set the margins of the second equals to the with of the first and third, like in the sample, it will fill up all the space.

You can look at it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/Bq2rw/